# ionic-plugin-deeplinksプラグインのインストールで「Error: spawnSync npm.cmd ENOENT」が発生する

Tags: npm, ionic2

Ionic2でURLをタップしたらアプリを起動するようにしたいのですが、やり方がわからず困っています。
[myapp://****]　左のようなURLをクリックしたらアプリを起動するようにできると思うのですが、いまいちうまくいきません。
Ionic2のホームページにあるionic-plugin-deeplinksを用いてできそうなのですが、プラグインのインストールでエラーが出てしまいます。
[Error: spawnSync npm.cmd ENOENT]
AndroidのPlatformが入っているとエラーが出るみたいなので、何か干渉しているみたいなのですがよくわかりません。
他のプラグインでもいいのですがcustom URL schemeで起動する方法があれば教えてください。

実際に行った手順
1.ionic start TestApp --v2
2.ionic pratform add android
3.ionic plugin add ionic-plugin-deeplinks --variable URL_SCHEME=myapp --variable DEEPLINK_SCHEME=https --variable DEEPLINK_HOST=example.com --variable ANDROID_PATH_PREFIX=/

発生したエラーコード

```
    Failed to install 'ionic-plugin-deeplinks':Error: spawnSync npm.cmd ENOENT
at exports._errnoException (util.js:1028:11)
at spawnSync (child_process.js:468:20)
at module.exports (C:\BFM\source\Linktest\plugins\ionic-plugin-deeplinks\hooks\beforePluginInstallHook.js:51:16)
at runScriptViaModuleLoader (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:187:18)
at runScript (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:165:16)
at C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\hooks\HooksRunner.js:133:20
at _fulfilled (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
at C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodist\bin\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:810:14
Error: spawnSync npm.cmd ENOENT
```

実行環境
npm:3.9.6
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.2.2

Comment: 関連　https://teratail.com/questions/67752

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらくこの部分の処理でのエラー発生でしょう。
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-deeplinks/blob/master/hooks/beforePluginInstallHook.js

```
var npm = (process.platform === "win32" ? "npm.cmd" : "npm");
var result = spawnSync(npm, ['install', '--production'], { cwd: './plugins/' + ctx.opts.plugin.id });
if (result.error) {
  throw result.error;
}
```

npm.cmdが見つからずに実行できないというエラーです。
nodeはインストールされていますでしょうか？

---

一応この部分についても補足しておきます。

> AndroidのPlatformが入っているとエラーが出るみたいなので、何か干渉しているみたいなのですがよくわかりません。

Android環境をビルドする為(apkを作成)に必要なファイル群が/platforms/android/配下に用意されます。プラグインを追加すると/platforms/配下の各環境に対して適用されます。
上記エラーが出るということは/platforms/android/配下のAndroid環境に対してプラグインを適用しようとしているということになります。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。nodeの6.2.2がインストールされています。

Comment: @nanokuma npm.cmdは実行できますか？

Comment: npm -v で 3.9.6と出るので通ってると思います　ビルドしてapkが作成できるのでおそらく大丈夫です

Comment: `npm`ではなく`npm.cmd`が実行できますか？Windows環境だと思いますが、おそらくnode.exeを実行するためのバッチファイルのようなnpm.cmdがあるのかと思います。それが実行できない為にエラーが発生しているのではないかと。

Comment: はい。バイナリ配布されているWindows用のzipファイルを確認したところnpm.cmdがありました。インストーラでインストールされたならnode.exeと同じフォルダにあるでしょう。ただ、配布されているnodeのバージョンは4.x以降となっており3.x系がどうなっているのかは確認できませんでした。また、ionic2のドキュメントを見ましたが`The CLI requires Node 4.X`と記載されており4.x以降が要求されているので、nodeのバージョンをあげることもお勧めします。

Comment: 失礼しました。`npm -v`だとnpmのバージョンですね。nodeのバージョンはまた別でしょうか。

Comment: nodistを使用しているので若干環境が違うかもしれませんが、いくつかの[npm.cmd]ファイルがあり、ほとんどが"throw err;"で実行できませんでした。node_modules\cordova\node_modules\.bin＞成功　node_modules\cordova\node_modules\npm\bin　＞　"throw err;"　  node_modules\ionic\node_modules\npm\bin　＞　"throw err;"　　　node_modules\npm-check-updates\node_modules\.bin ＞ 成功  node_modules\npm-check-updates\node_modules\npm\bin > "throw err;"  \npmv\3.9.6\bin > 成功

Comment: なるほどnodistでバージョン管理されているのですね。環境に関する情報や試して発生したエラーなどは質問内容を編集して追記していただけますか？

Comment: すみません意図がうまく伝わっていなかったようですが1つ1つ実行して欲しいという質問ではなく、プラグインのインストールコマンドを実行している同じ環境で`npm.cmd`が実行できるかどうかを確認して欲しいという質問です。あとコマンドプロンプトから実行されてますか？

Comment: コマンドプロンプトから実行しています。'npm.cmd' は、内部コマンドまたは外部コマンド、操作可能なプログラムまたはバッチ ファイルとして認識されていません。　ここにパスを通せばいいのでしょうか?

Comment: パスを通せばいいのはその通りなのですが、nodistなどでバージョン管理されているのであればnodistの設定によりパスは通されていそうな気がします。とりあえずパスを通してみて動くならそれでOKとするか、問題が出る（または強引な設定での環境が気になる）であればnodistのインストールからやり直した方がいいかもしれません。今はnodistのインストーラは環境変数など自動で設定してくれるようです。

Comment: maot様の見解通りnodist/nodeの環境問題っぽかったです。nodist/nodeをアンインストールして最新のnodist[0.8.8]をインストールし、nodeの6系の最新[6.10.0]を入れてみたら無事に動きました。本当にありがとうございました。